# Conditional rand

Tags: arrays, c

this code gives a 4x3 array of numbers from 2 to 100:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LINES 4
#define COLUMNS 3

int main(void) {
  int matriz[LINES][COLUMNS];
  int i, j;
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i = 0; i < LINES; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++){
        matriz[i][j] = rand() % 99 + 2;
    }
  }
  printf("Matriz[%i][%i]:\n", LINES, COLUMNS);
  for(i = 0; i < LINES; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++){
      printf("\t%i", matriz[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

what can I do so this array only receive EVEN numbers from the rand function?

Comment: Call rand only twice? .

Comment: I think you mean **even** numbers ... try `matriz[i][j] = rand() % 50 * 2;` for `0, 2, 4, 6, ..., 98` *(even number (EN) ==> número par [PT])*

Comment: Unrelated: you may prefer https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Easy way - generate random numbers between 1 and 50 and multiply by 2.

Comment: Instead of `rand()` could use [Dilbert Random Number Generator](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)() * 2.